# Is "array[x][y]" always calculated with pointer arithmetic?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, malloc, pointer-arithmetic

From what I understand in C:

When you declare a 2D array like `int array[x][y] = {0};`, the program gets a chunk of memory (x*y) `int`'s long.

When you malloc a 2D array like:

```
int ** array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * x);
for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * y)};
```

The program gets a chunk of memory (x `int*`'s) + (x*y) `int`'s long.

The problem I have is this: When you later type `array[5][0]`, what happens? Does the program always treat it as pointer arithmetic (this would suggest the compiler creates an array of pointers for you when you declare an array)? Or does the compiler treat that statement differently depending on how you created the array?

Edit: changed "int * array" to "int ** array"

Comment: *"The program gets a chunk of memory (x `int*`'s) + `(x*y) int`'s long."* should be *"the program gets a chunk of memory (x `int*`'s) long, and `x` chunks of memory (y `int`'s) long."*

Comment: As an aside, avoid `sizeof(TYPE)`, prefer `sizeof *pointer`, the latter is less error-prone and couples the size to the target, instead of some manually resolved type, which might be wrong, or outdated.

Comment: `int ** array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * x);` is not allocating a 2D array, as `int **` is not a 2D array, but a double pointer.  The pointed to values must be pointers and not `int`s, as required by a 2D `int` array.

Answer (score 2):

The big innovation which C added over its predecessor B, is that there is no place the base-pointer of an array is stored, which among other things means that the name does not name a pointer to the first element, but the array itself.

Whether an array is an array of fundamental type, of user-defined type (struct, union) or of an array type does not change anything.

Thus, yes, the array decays to a pointer, which is used for pointer arithmetic (array-indexing ironically, which is sugar for pointer-arithmetic plus dereferencing), yielding an array element which is of array type, and after pointer-decay is in turn used in pointer-arithmetic.

All intermediate values calculated are just that, and need not be stored anywhere else.

Your second example is not actually a multi-dimensional array, but an array of pointers, a different beast though using the same syntax for accessing.

Comment: So you're saying there's a major difference between an array of pointers and a "true" multidimensional array besides how they are stored?

Comment: Yes. A multidimensional array is really an array (of array)+ of type. While an array of pointers is accessed with the same syntax, the underlying mechanics are different. The former uses pointer arithmetic and array decay, the other pointer arithmetic and reading chaining pointers.

Comment: So when someone types `array[3][0]`, it could be treated differently depending on how the array is stored?

Comment: @LukeDunn Depending on the type of array. If it is an array of array of type, an array of pointers to type, a pointer to pointer to type, or even a pointer to array of type.

Answer (score 2):

C uses the types of operands to decide how to evaluate them.

If `array` is an `int [x][y]`, then, in `array[5][0]`:

- `array` is an array, so it is automatically converted to a pointer to its initial element. Let’s call the value of this pointer *p*.
- Then `p[5]` refers to the element of `array` with index 5.
- `p[5]` is also an array, so it is converted to a pointer to its initial element. Let’s call the value of this pointer *q*.
- Then `q[0]` refers to the element of `p[5]` with index 0.
- Thus, we have element 0 of element 5 of `array`.

If `array` is an `int **`, then, in `array[5][0]`:

- `array` is an lvalue that is not of array type, so it is automatically converted to the value stored in it. Note that, when `array` is array type, a pointer to its first element is **calculated** from knowing where the array is stored. Here, where `array` does not have array type, the value is fetched from memory. Again, let’s call the loaded value *p*.
- Then `p[5]` refers to the element with index 5, given that there is an array of elements stored where *p* points.
- Because the type of `array` is `int **`, the things it points to have type `int *`. So `p[5]` has type `int *`.
- `p[5]` is an lvalue that is not of array type, so it is automatically converted to the value stored in it. Again, this is done by loading the stored value from memory. Let’s call the loaded value *q*.
- `q[0]` refers to the element that *q* points to. Thus, we have the element at offset 0 from where `p[5]` points, and `p[5]` is the element at offset 5 from where `array` points.

So `array[5][0]` is not calculated the same way. When it is an array of arrays, the memory addresses are calculated from the base address of `array`. When it is an `int **`, the memory addresses are calculated by loading pointers from memory.

### Note

lvalue conversion is so automatic and ubiquitous that we often do not think about it. In `x = y + z;`, `y` and `z` refer to objects, and the values of those objects are automatically loaded and used in the expression. This is called *lvalue conversion*. `x` also refers to an object, but it is not converted to its value because there is an exception for the left operand of an assignment operator. (The conversion also does not occur when an lvalue is the operand of `sizeof`, unary `&`, `++`, or `--` or is the left operand of `.`.)

In some languages, there is no automatic lvalue conversion, and you have to load values explicitly. For example, in BLISS, you have to write `x = .y + .z`, where the `.` indicates to load the value.

Answer (score 1):

Array indexing is equivalent to pointer arithmetic plus a dereference.  Specifically, `E1[E2]` is exactly the same as `*((E1) + (E2))`

In the case of either a 2D array or a pointer-to-pointer this happens twice.  Given your example of `array[5][0]`, this is the same as `*(array[5] + 0)` which is the same as `*(*(array + 5) + 0)`.

As for what happens in terms of pointer arithmetic, first let's look at the 2D array case.  In the expression `array + 5`, `array` is converted to a pointer to its first element and thus has type `int(*)[y]`.  So adding 5 to this pointer moves the resulting pointer up by the size of what it points to (i.e. a `int[y]`) times 5.

For a pointer to pointer, `array + 5` moves the resulting point up by the size of what *it* points to (i.e. a `int *`) times 5.

So it's the exact same expression, but the pointer arithmetic is different because what is being pointed to is different.

Comment: Actually, `int(*)[y]` and `int[y]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid - it should be:

```
int **array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * x);

//or better

int **array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * x);
```

But this way you do not allocate 2D array only an array of pointers.

In this case, program has to dereference the array of pointers first. Then using this pointer the second index will reference the int value. It is not very efficient as requires at least two reads from the memory.

2D array is allocated as one chunk of memory. The position of element in the memory is calculated by the program without additioal reads from the memory. https://godbolt.org/z/5adjqxeKP

To dynamically allocate 2d array you need to use pointer to array:

```
int (*array)[x] = malloc(sizeof(*array) * y);
int (*array1)[x][Y] = malloc(sizeof(*array));
```

and referencing :

```
array[3][2] = 5;

(*array1)[4][5] = 6;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pictures may help.  For the sake of space, we’ll assume `x` and `y` are 2.  Given the declaration

```
int arr[2][2];
```

we get this in memory:

```
     int
     +–––+
arr: |   | arr[0][0]
     +–––+
     |   | arr[0][1]
     +–––+
     |   | arr[1][0]
     +–—-+ 
     |   | arr[1][1]
     +–––+
```

Note that no space is set aside for any pointers - there is no object `arr` separate from the array elements themselves.

For the code

```
int **arr = malloc( 2 * sizeof *arr );
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
  arr[i] = malloc( 2 * sizeof *arr[i] );
```

we get this:

```
     int **    int *              int
     +–––+     +–––+              +–––+
arr: |   | -–> |   | arr[0] ––––> |   | arr[0][0]
     +–––+     +–––+              +–––+
               |   | arr[1] ––+   |   | arr[0][1]
               +–––+          |   +–––+
                              |
                              |   +–––+
                              +–> |   | arr[1][0]
                                  +–––+
                                  |   | arr[1][1]
                                  +–––+
```

In this case, you have *three* pointers - `arr` points to a *sequence* of pointers, each of which points to a sequence of `int`.

So, how is `arr[x][y]` evaluated for each?

Remember that the expression `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - given an address `a`, offset `i` *elements* (not bytes!) from that address and dereference the result.

```
arr[i][j] == *(arr[i] + j) == *(*(arr + i) + j)
```

This is evaluated exactly the same if `arr` is a 2D array of `int` or pointer to a pointer to `int`.

In the second case, things are pretty obvious - we're dealing with a bunch of explicit pointers.  `arr` explicitly stores the address of `arr[0]`, `arr[0]` explicitly stores the address of `arr[0][0]`, etc.  So it's entirely logical that `arr[i] == *(arr + i)` and `arr[i][j] == *(*(arr + i) + j)`.

But what about the first case?  No pointers are explicitly stored anywhere.  `arr` doesn't store the address of `arr[0]` (there *is* no separate `arr[0]`, which means there's nothing to store the address of `arr[0][0]`).  So how can `arr[i][j]` be evaluated as `*(*(arr + i) + j)`?

Like so - unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize an array of `char`, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When the compiler sees the *expression* `arr` in your code, unless that expression is the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`, it *replaces* that expression with a pointer, and the value of that pointer is the address of the first element of the array.  Similarly, the expression `arr[i]` is also replaced with a pointer, and that pointer value is the address of `arr[i][0]`.  Note in this case that `arr` decays to type "pointer to *2-element array of* `int`" (`int (*)[2]`), not "pointer to pointer to `int`".

```
Expression    Type          Decays to    Value
----------    ----          ---------    -----
       arr    int [2][2]    int (*)[2]   Same as &arr[0]
      *arr    int [2]       int *        Same as arr[0]
    arr[i]    int [2]       int *        Same as &arr[i][0]
   *arr[i]    int           n/a          Same as arr[0][0]
 arr[i][j]    int           n/a

      &arr    int (*)[2][2] n/a          Address of array object
   &arr[i]    int (*)[2]    n/a          Address of the i'th subarray
```

So we can think of `arr[i][j]` as being evaluated like so:

```
*(*(&arr[0] + i) + j)
```

The address of an array is the same as the address of its first element - the expressions `&arr`, `arr`, `&arr[0]`, `arr[0]`, and `&arr[0][0]` all yield the same address value, but the *types* of the expressions are different - `int (*)[2][2]`, `int (*)[2]`, `int (*)[2]`, `int [2] => int *`, and `int *` (which may affect how that pointer value is represented - it's possible for `int (*)[2]` to have a different representation from `int *`, although that's not the case on any system you're likely to encounter).

Remember how pointer arithmetic works - if `p` points to an object of type `T`, then `p + 1` yields the address of the next *object* of that type.  If `arr` points to a 2-element array of `int`, then `arr + 1` yields the address of the next *2-element array* of `int`.  Going back to our first picture, but now with some additional expressions:

```
 int                 int (*)[2][2]  int (*)[2]  int *
 +–––+               -------------  ----------  -----
 |   | arr[0][0] <-- &arr           arr         *arr + 0       (arr[0] + 0)
 +–––+      
 |   | arr[0][1] <--                            *arr + 1       (arr[0] + 1)
 +–––+
 |   | arr[1][0] <--                arr + 1     *(arr + 1) + 0 (arr[1] + 0)
 +–—-+ 
 |   | arr[1][1] <--                            *(arr + 1) + 1 (arr[1] + 1)
 +–––+
```

Again, whenever the compiler sees `arr` in an expression, it replaces it with the value of `&arr[0]` and uses pointer arithmetic to do the subscripting.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
int variable[5][10];
```

declares variable as a single array of 5 elements, which are all of type `int[10]` (an array of 10 elements), whose cell size (assuming an int is 4 bytes) is 10*4 = 40 bytes.  This means that `variable[3]` is the fourth element, positioned at the address of variable plus 3x40 = 120 bytes.

And there, there is an array of 10 `int`s, if you try to acces the third element (`variable[3][2]`) you will have to add 2x`sizeof(int)` which is 8 bytes more.

So, yes, for a 2D array, pointer arithmetic works as it does for 1D arrays.  But when you allocate something dynamically with malloc, you need to know that the compiler manages array types (the types thar are `sometype[n][m]` with different `n` and `m` as different types, and *all types in C must be known at compilation time --this is part of the static typing characteristic of C--)

if you want to use some way of specifying dynamic arrays (arrays that are accessed with the notation `[a][b]...[z]`) in C in which space is allocated dynamically and only the needed space is allocated... you have to use pointers to solve all the intermediate accesses, as the runtime has no information about array dimensioning, because you have used pointers, not array types.  You cannot declare an array type and leave it incomplete... you use a pointer for that.  Even in parameter declaration, when you declare a parameter of an array type, it is automatically converted into a pointer... because you cannot pass an array by value, and the c language doesn't check array bounds.

So pointer arithmetic is one dimensional in nature, and you use pointers for dynamic arrays... no size of cells (or rows) is known to the compiler... so it cannot assume that each row cell is 26 integers size or less... you need to put a pointer to the start of the data (solving the previous to last computation) and you have to create axbxc....xy y-pointers (double, triple, fourthly, etc.) until you allocate the full array.

How can this be done (e.g. to handle a 2D matrix of `n` by `m`)?

```
    double **m = malloc(n * sizeof(*m));  /* size of n pointers to double */
    assert(m != NULL);
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        m[row] = malloc(m * sizeof m[row][0]); 
        assert(m[row] != NULL);
    }
```

this will allocate a pseudo matrix in which `m[3][2]` will be a valid `double` element and can be accessed, but `m[2]` is not an array of `m` elements, but a pointer to an array of `m` elements.